# If $\sum a_{n}$ is a series of positive terms and $b_{n} = (a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+ \dots +a_{n})/n$ then $\sum b_{n}$ is divergent. (True/false)

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum a_{n}$ is a series of positive terms and $b_{n} = (a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+ \dots +a_{n})/n$ then $\sum b_{n}$ is divergent. (True/false)

The statement is given true with a proof in my book.
But I'm confused.
If I take the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{2}}, $ for which sequence of partial sum is $a_{n} = (1)+(1/4)+(1/9)+(1/16)+ \dots$ then,sequence of partial sum for $\sum {b_{n}} $ will be $b_{n} = (1/2)+(1/8)+(1/18)+ \dots$ which is convergent. 
Then why is this statement true?

Answer (score 5):

This follows by series comparison. Since $b_n \ge \frac{a_1}{n}$, the terms of the series $\sum_n b_n$ are bounded from below by a multiple of the harmonic series, which is divergent,

Comment: I was just adding my answer when you posted yours. As they're basically the same, although I provide a bit more detail, I can delete mine if you wish.

Answer (score 5):

Given that $a_i$ are all positive and

$$b_n = \left(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots + a_n\right)/n \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Then note that $b_n \ge \frac{a_1}{n}$ for all $n \ge 1$. Thus,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} b_i \ge \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{a_1}{n} = a_1 \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Note that the latter part is the harmonic series, which diverges.

Comment: Yes, I have read this proof. But, what is wrong with my example?

Comment: Note that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, but $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, so you can select $a_i$ for the latter case which will allow $\sum b_i$ to converge.

Comment: @Mathsaddict I misread your original text. Using $a_i = \frac{1}{i^2}$, then $b_1 = \frac{a_1}{1} = 1$, not $\frac{1}{2}$. Next, $b_2 = \frac{a_1 + a_2}{2} = \frac{1 + 1/4}{2} = \frac{5}{8}$, not $\frac{1}{8}$. If you continue, you will see the next values are larger than you indicated, and don't become small enough, fast enough, for the sum to converge, as another answer here already states.

Comment: yes, I calculated $b_{n}$ incorrectly. So, this series $\sum b_{n}$ will always be divergent. It doesn't matter if $\sum a_{n}$ is convergent or not. Right?

Comment: @Mathsaddict Yes, you are correct. That is what my proof, and basically the same one of Hans Engler, shows.